# Rails ActionMailer not sending emails in production; no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

This code works perfectly on development and the email never arrives in production, even though they have the same configuration.

Config:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'domain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'my_server@gmail.com',
    :password => 'secret',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Sending the email:

```
logger.warn "before mail call"
logger.warn ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
logger.warn(mail(to: "my_email@gmail.com", subject: "Testing", body: "email body").deliver!)
```

Server logs:

```
[2013-08-29 16:41:11.000] [WARN] -- before mail call
[2013-08-29 16:41:11.000] [WARN] -- {:address=>"smtp.gmail.com", :port=>587, :authentication=>:plain, :user_name=>"my_server@gmail.com", :password=>"secret", :enable_starttls_auto=>true}
[2013-08-29 16:41:11.000] [WARN] -- Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 16:41:11 +0200
From: my_server@gmail.com
To: my_email@gmail.com
Message-ID: <521f5d87537af_7af3da480050052@castillo05.fzi.de.mail>
Subject: Testing
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

email body
```

In development on my localhost it works perfectly. The email arrives almost instantly. On production the email never arrives and I get no error. I have already tried so many combinations of settings (with/without :enable_starttls_auto, :domain, not setting delivery_method, perform_deliveries, etc) and nothing has worked so far. I have also tried sending to other emails with no success.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @GeorgeMillo yes, it was actually quite  a silly mistake. `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` was being overwritten at the end of the file to `test` and therefore none were being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a from address (that is a valid email address) to your mail settings. I've had emails blocked before for this very reason. Maybe something like admin @ the domain name your site is hosted on?

```
mail(to: "my_email@gmail.com", subject: "Testing", body: "email body", from: "me@mydomainname.com").deliver!
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it didn't work either. Shouldn't I get an error somewhere?

Comment: well the fact that it works in development,and doesn't error,  suggests to me that it isn't really an action mailer problem and that it's more likely something to do with the server - either it's blocking or not capable of sending email. Have you got a server admin you can liaise with?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your logs, it looks like you are going it right in the code department.
The problem could be in your SMTP settings.

In particular, this post http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm is saying that gmail's smtp port in use is 465, I see you are using 587.